# Can istio use existing services?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I already have some services in my k8s cluster and want to mantain them separately. Examples:

- grafana with custom dashboards and custom dockerfile
- prometheus-operator instead of basic prometheus
- jaeger pointing to elasticsearch as internal storage
- certmanager in my own namespace (also I use it for nginx-ingress legacy routing)

Is it possible to use existing instances instead of creating istio-specific ones? Can istio communicate with them or it's hardcoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it is possible to use external services with istio. You can disable grafana and prometheus just by setting proper flags in values.yaml of istio helm chart (grafana.enabled=false, etc).
You can check [kyma-project](https://github.com/kyma-project) project to see how istio is integrated with prometheus-operator, grafana deployment with custom dashboards, and custom jaeger deployment. From your list only certmanager is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes provides quite a big variety of Networking and Load Balancing features from the box. However, the idea to simplify and extend the functionality  of [Istio sidecars](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/sidecar-injection/#automatic-sidecar-injection) is a good choice as they are used for automatic injection into the Pods in order to proxy the traffic between internal Kubernetes services.

You can implement `sidecars` manually or automatically. If you choose the manual way, make sure to add the appropriate parameter under Pod's annotation field:

```
annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
```

Automatic `sidecar` injection requires [Mutating Webhook admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/), available since Kubernetes version 1.9 released, therefore `sidecars` can be integrated for Pod's creation process as well.

Get yourself familiar with this [Article](https://medium.com/@timfpark/more-batteries-included-microservices-made-easier-with-istio-on-kubernetes-87c8b76ac2ef) to shed light on using different monitoring and traffic management tools in Istio.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I've pointed to another problem.

Istio installs _own_ set of external services like prometheus, and I didn't find the way how reuse existing.

Suppose I already have prometheus installed from official chart. It lovely customised and fits with my cluster vision :)
But,  Istio installs own (custom?) prometheus instance and image. It's ok until I want to use Istio's metrics in own purposes. I had to deal with two prometheus instances, resources they consume, etc.

Comment: Check this [Doc](https://istio-releases.github.io/v0.1/docs/tasks/metrics-logs.html) about collecting metrics and logs in Istio.